# Smooth Scrolling JavaScript work on all A tags

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following JavaScript Code for smoothing scrolling:

```js
$(document).on('click', 'a', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top
    }, 500);
});
```

Now I can't use other a links on my website. When I do this:
    LINK
nothing happened.

My website:
http://www.be-virtual.org/schnittchen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently it targets all the `<a>` tag. Change your selector correctly to target only those start with `#`:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[href^="#"]', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top
    }, 500);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. Must i add everytime the whole code for every link? i have 4 of that smooth links.

Comment: @DierigPatrick Just add the above code **once** in your JavaScript that gets loaded in your page.

Comment: ah now i understand the code :D
a[href^="#"]' stands for all links with a "#" in his href :)